# How to find the min and max values of an index in nested lists with matching strings?

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains tide data, the first few lines are:

> Thursday 4 January,11.58,0.38 meters
>
> Thursday 4 January,16.95,0.73 meters
>
> Thursday 4 January,23.68,0.02 meters
>
> Friday 5 January,6.48,0.83 meters
>
> Friday 5 January,12.42,0.33 meters

etc. and it continues for 5 more days of data.

I've turned this data into a nested list so it now prints as:

```
[['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73], ['Thursday 4 January', 23.68, 0.02], ['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33].....]
```

And so on for every line of data in the file, with the first index of each list being the day in a string, and the 2nd and 3rd index being floats.

For each nested list with a matching [0] index (the day), I need to find the lowest and highest float of each matching nested lists [2] index (the tide height) and print these to the screen for each day.

for example:

```
Thursday 4 January: 0.02 meters at lowest and 0.73 meters at highest
Friday 5 January: 0.33 meters at lowest and 0.83 meters at highest
```

Since the lists are in order by day already, I was thinking to just count the matching names and then compare it manually, e.g. for 'Thursday 4 January', since there are 3 of them, I just compare split_tides[0-2][2] and find the min and max, and repeat for each day. But I thought there must be a way to automatically compare nested lists that have a matching string.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Image of text file

[image]

Comment: Can you guarantee that a particular day results will always come together?

Comment: @Austin yes, the days are always in order and grouped together if that's what you mean. I'll add the text file to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can use `groupby` to group by date and `sort` by the 3rd index height. Sample code here:

```
    from itertools import groupby
    from operator import itemgetter

    data = [['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73], ['Thursday 4 January', 23.68, 0.02],
         ['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33]]

    for k, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
        a = sorted(g, key=itemgetter(2))
        print('{}: {} meters at lowest and {} meters at highest'.format(k, a[0][2], a[-1][2]))
```

output:

```
Thursday 4 January: 0.02 meters at lowest and 0.73 meters at highest
Friday 5 January: 0.33 meters at lowest and 0.83 meters at highest
```

By the way, make sure your data is ordered by date before using `groupby` in date.

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 2):

Here below is the snippet which would help you

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = [['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73], ['Thursday 4 January', 23.68, 0.02],
         ['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33]]

df = DataFrame.from_records(data)

df.columns = ["Date", "Value", "Height"]

df.groupby(['Date'])['Height'].max()
df.groupby(['Date'])['Height'].min()
```

Output:

Date
Friday 5 January      0.83
Thursday 4 January    0.73

Date
Friday 5 January      0.33
Thursday 4 January    0.02

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['Thursday 4 January', 11.58, 0.38], ['Thursday 4 January', 16.95, 0.73], ['Thursday 4 January', 23.68, 0.02], ['Friday 5 January', 6.48, 0.83], ['Friday 5 January', 12.42, 0.33]]

dic={'day':[],'min':[],'max':[]}
for i in data :
    dic['day']+=[i[0]]
    dic['min']+=[i[1]]
    dic['max']+=[i[2]]



from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(dict)

for i in dic['day']:
    x[i]={'min':[],'max':[]}

for i in range(len(dic['min'])):
    x[dic['day'][i]]['min']+=[dic['min'][i]]
    x[dic['day'][i]]['max']+=[dic['max'][i]]

print(dict(x))
"""
structure data for future use

{'Friday 5 January': {'max': [0.83, 0.33], 'min': [6.48, 12.42]},
 'Thursday 4 January': {'max': [0.38, 0.73, 0.02],
  'min': [11.58, 16.95, 23.68]}}
"""



result =[]
for i in x:
    result.append(r'{}: {} meters at lowest an {} meters at highest'.format(i,min(x[i]['min']),max(x[i]['max'])))


print(result)

"""output

['Thursday 4 January: 11.58 meters at lowest an 0.73 meters at highest', 'Friday 5 January: 6.48 meters at lowest an 0.83 meters at highest']
""""
```